# Tab bar items hiding using SWReveal View Controller

Tags: ios, swift, swrevealviewcontroller

I'm using `SWRevealViewController` with `TabBar Controller` as front and a VC in which I have placed `TableView` as a rear view for `SWReveal VC`.
My UI Looks like this,

[image]

Now when I click on table view and want to open first tab bar VC it hides my Tab bar from the bottom. Through this code I try to open my `TabBar Controller`,

```
var menuVCBeforeLoginArray = ["NewsVC","BookmarkVC","MessageVC"]
let vcIdentifier = menuVCBeforeLoginArray[indexPath.row]
    let vc = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: vcIdentifier)
    let navVC = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: vc)
    self.revealViewController().pushFrontViewController(navVC, animated: true)
```

Now when it opens the first tab bar it looks like this with hidden bottom bar.

[image]

How can I show the bottom bar even when I open VC from side menu?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not push with selected viewcontroller with a `navigation controller`. Get the `tabbar controller` and change `selectedIndex`

```
//var menuVCBeforeLoginArray = ["NewsVC","BookmarkVC","MessageVC"]
//let vcIdentifier = menuVCBeforeLoginArray[indexPath.row]
//let vc = storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: vcIdentifier)
//let navVC = UINavigationController.init(rootViewController: vc)
//self.revealViewController().pushFrontViewController(navVC, animated: true)

if let tabBarController = self.revealViewController().frontViewController as? UITabBarController {
    tabBarController.selectedIndex = indexPath.row
}
```